# Unable to view one database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to an organization, and there was a SQL Server link set up before I started between to servers.  There are 12 databases on the linked server, and I can access all of them but one.  For example, I run `[SELECT * FROM [SERVER].Database.dbo.table1]` and get a result set.  And this is the case for all databases except 1.   I run `[SELECT * FROM [SERVER].Database2.dbo.table1`] on that one and get "The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER" does not contain the table ""Database2"."dbo"."Table1"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.   The table exists, and I am able to select from it on the originating server with no issues.  I am logging in with windows authentication. Any ideas?

I have verified that I have the same database permissions on 1 that I can reference as the one I cannot.

Comment: The user that the linked server is using does not have permission on that database.

Comment: Just because a table exists on one server does not mean it exists on another server.  Just because a table has one set of rights on one server does not mean it is the same on the other.

Comment: It's a long shot, but it is possible that the DB was somehow moved or restored in such a way that the server login and database user does not have a matching security identifier.  Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 to see if that might help.